# Check for existence of wget/curl

Tags: linux, shell

Trying to do a script to download a file using wget, or curl if wget doesn't exist in Linux.  How do I have the script check for existence of wget?

Comment: [Similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script) Question can help you with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
wget http://download/url/file 2>/dev/null || curl -O  http://download/url/file
```

Comment: Note that for this answer, if the user has both wget and curl installed, then this will also run curl if wget fails (for example, the file 404'd.)

Answer (score 12):

Linux has a `which` command which will check for the existence of an executable on your path:

```sh
pax> which ls ; echo $?
/bin/ls
0

pax> which no_such_executable ; echo $?
1
```

As you can see, it sets the return code `$?` to easily tell if the executable was found, so you could use something like:

```sh
if which wget >/dev/null ; then
    echo "Downloading via wget."
    wget --option argument
elif which curl >/dev/null ; then
    echo "Downloading via curl."
    curl --option argument
else
    echo "Cannot download, neither wget nor curl is available."
fi
```

Comment: If someone would just want the exit code one could only use `which ls 1&>1; echo $?`

Answer (score 5):

One can also use `command` or `type` or `hash` to check if wget/curl exists or not. Another thread here - "[Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)" answers very nicely what to use in a bash script to check if a program exists.

I would do this -

```
if [ ! -x /usr/bin/wget ] ; then
    # some extra check if wget is not installed at the usual place                                                                           
    command -v wget >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "Please install wget or set it in your path. Aborting."; exit 1; }
fi
```

Comment: good solution, thanks for linking to the other thread about `command` as well, helpful info, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is try install to install `wget` with your usual package management system,. It should tell you if already installed;

```
yum -y wget
```

Otherwise just launch a command like below

```
wget http://download/url/file
```

If you receive no error, then its ok.

Answer (score 2):

A solution taken from the K3S install script (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rancher/k3s/master/install.sh)

```sh
function download {
    url=$1
    filename=$2

    if [ -x "$(which wget)" ] ; then
        wget -q $url -O $2
    elif [ -x "$(which curl)" ]; then
        curl -o $2 -sfL $url
    else
        echo "Could not find curl or wget, please install one." >&2
    fi
}
# to use in the script:
download https://url /local/path/to/download
```

Explanation:
It looks for the location of `wget` and checks for a file to exist there, if so, it does a script-friendly (i.e. quiet) download. If wget isn't found, it tries `curl` in a similarly script-friendly way.

(Note that the question doesn't specify BASH however my answer assumes it.)

Answer (score -2):

Simply run

```
wget http://download/url/file
```

you will see the statistics whether the endpoint is available or not.

Comment: we need to check programatically if this program exists or not.